# Cannot parseInt on the first line of a file

Tags: java

I have a simple text file, each line has a number and then some other data, like this:

> ```
> 1 somedata someotherdata 
> 2 randomstuff notimportant
> ```

I want the read the file and for each line use parseInt() on the number. My (simplified) code:

```
File file = new File("data.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
  String splitLine[] = line.split(" ");
  int number = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]);          
  String str1 = splitLine[1];
  String str2 = splitLine[2];
  // do some stuff with the data 
}
```

For the most part this works... except for the first line of the file. There's no issue at all with reading the first line and splitting it. There is also no issue when using parseInt() for all subsequent lines. Yet when I try to parseInt() that first number on the first line, I get a NumberFormatException. Nothing seems wrong with the text file itself, every line is identical in formatting. Why could this be?

Comment: What does the exception show? It should display the value it's trying to parse, so you don't need to guess what's happening.

Comment: What is `splitLine[0]` on the first line?

Comment: The exception displays the correct value. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"

Comment: Are you sure there is not special unprintable character? (use a debugger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saving with Microsoft software? Some tools add the controversial[1](http://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.boms) "utf-8 BOM"[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) sequence to the beginning of the text file, which is not interpreted specially by Java.

Two sensible courses of action if this is the case:

1. Ensure the file is not saved with a BOM. (There is usually an option in the "save as" dialog for this.)
2. Check for the presence of the BOM (`"\uFEFF"`) and remove it if it is at the start of the first line of the file.

Comment: I just went ahead and made a new txt file in gedit and it works now. Previously I had made the txt file in LibreOffice, so I guess it was the culprit

Comment: 3. leave first line empty and skip it... [:-|