# How "contains()" method really work on List<string>?

Tags: java, contains

I am trying to check if two lists contain the same value and I can't figure out why one this specific value triggers my FileException

```
private static void checkFileHeaders(List<ColumnDefinition> columnsDefinitions, ArrayList<String> columnsName) throws FileException {
    for (ColumnDefinition cd : columnsDefinitions) {
        if(!columnsName.contains(cd.getFieldNameInFile())) {
            throw new FileException("Parameter "+cd.getFieldNameInFile() +" missing ");
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see in the debugger, my value exists in the list, can it be something with the encoding? It works with other values but not this specific one.

I am aware contains() works like equals() so what is wrong here

[image]

If I look at the individual characters :

cd.getFieldNameInFile() : [90, 66, 75, 80, 70, 45, 66, 85, 75, 82, 83]

columnsName[0] : [-1, -2, 90, 0, 66, 0, 75, 0, 80, 0, 70, 0, 45, 0, 66, 0, 85, 0, 75, 0, 82, 0, 83, 0]

How to solve this difference and what is the reason?

Comment: According to the documentation, "returns `true` if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`." Are you sure the returned expression doesn't have a trailing whitespace?

Comment: If you expand the String item in the debugger you can see the individual characters of the string. Expand the two strings that should be equal and ensure they have the same characters.

Comment: Encode both in Base64 and then compare

Comment: I have no whitespace in the value stored in cd.getFieldNameInFile()

Comment: @eric.m they actually do not have the same individual characters, meaning the encoding is not the same for both?

Comment: Please show the difference.

Comment: Are you comparing the same data types? If you compare ColumnDefinition to String, they will never be equal (check the equals contract), but the debugger will use their `toString` method to display the value, so they will look equal.

Comment: Maybe the - is different utf-8 dash? Could you edit the message to include the char's (numeric) of which both strings consist?

Comment: Are you sure `throw new FileException` is being thrown in the first iteration?

Comment: Could you show the stacktrace and the class `ColumnDefinition`

Comment: post the exception; check result of `columnsName.get(0).equals(cd.getFieldNameInFile())`

Comment: I have edited my question, seems like both values are not exactly the same if we look at each character..?

Comment: column name probably came from file with BOM (windows? UTF-8/UTF-16 coding) - probably you just need to change the reading/ of that values (but since we have no [mcve] it is just a wild guess)

Comment: the columname actually comes from a file and I am using a BufferedReader

Comment: Could you add the code of where these column names are coming from? Those 0s are probably unprintable NULL-bytes. As for the negative bytes I'm not sure.. I guess they are unsigned bytes and also some other type of unprintable character. But as @CarlosHeuberger mentioned, those column names probably came from the file in a certain encoding, and you are using a different encoding in your BufferedReader.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen nope that is definitevly UTF-16 ; 2 first bytes are FF FE (BOM - Byte Order Marker); followed by 2 bytes for each character (since ASCII higher order is zero)

Comment: I have tried to encode both values in base64 and here is what I got for cd.getFieldNameInFile() : WkJLUEYtQlVLUlM=  and for the columnname value : 77u/WkJLUEYtQlVLUlM=   I do believe the 77u/ means it is UTF8 encoded, or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: probably similar problem to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57726475/85421 that is, file starts with UTF-8 BOM (I just wonder that `equals` does not handle that correctly, probably because reading with wrong charset....)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger omg you are correct, I did save my file with windows notepad and it is UTF8-BOM... just fixed it in notepad++.

Comment: consider to post it as answer, I will simply do some testing to remove these first characters when there are any, as proposed in the linked question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks for each element, if it is `equal()` to the element you are testing against.. Meaning, if the two elements pass the `equals()` method test, the `contains()` method will return true for them, if the `equals()` method returns false, so will the `contains()` method.

### From the Java doc:

> boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

#### Doc Link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0):

Evidently `getFieldNameInFile` is not a String. So one should take a `toString`,

```
private static void checkFileHeaders(List<ColumnDefinition> columnsDefinitions,
        List<String> columnsName) throws FileException {
    for (ColumnDefinition cd : columnsDefinitions) {
        if(!columnsName.contains(cd.getFieldNameInFile().toString()) {
            throw new FileException("Parameter "+cd.getFieldNameInFile() +" missing ");
        }
    }
}
```

With Streams:

```
private static void checkFileHeaders(List<ColumnDefinition> columnsDefinitions,
        Set<String> columnsName) throws FileException {
    if (columnsDefinitions.streams
            .map(ColumnDefinition::getFieldNameInFile)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .anyMatch(nm -> !columnsName.contains(nm)) {
        throw new FileException("Parameter " + cd.getFieldNameInFile() + " missing ");
    }
}
```

Furthermore `ArrayList` it too specific, use an interface, `List` as this method can work for any kind of List implementation.

And `Set<String>` would be much faster for `contains`, a `HashSet<>` for instance.

Comment: It is a string --

Comment: Why should it not be a String? just using UTF-16LE (apparently)

Comment: The difference in the debugger where the double quotes were missing which led me to that idea. I thought an Expression or such

Comment: the Expression View in Eclipse (my guess) does not show them for a String expression (a bit *inconsistent*)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger right (now behind an IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: In this case the original code is okay. if the list `columnsName` stems from the first line of a CSV file, it might very well be the case that the file is in UTF-8 encoding, with an extra invisible BOM character as 1 char in the file, which would mess up the first column's name with an invisible char. `toCharArray()` would show it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

What we omit to cosider is that even if an `equals()` method is defined for a class still the `hashCode()` method is something to care about (even if here you are supposing to compare Strings maybe not?).

**Why ?**

`contains` depends on `equals` and equals works with `hashCode` to tell if we are talking about the same object here in term of reference.

To resume `contains()` work on `equals-hashCode` contract basis
[More documentation](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-hashcode-equals-contract-set-contains/)